# anonymize emails in web logs using sed using regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

If it helps I am using sed for windows http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

I have log files that look like this

```
205.200.253.76 6bTxPVZ2aOXEQ5C jamesbond.2015@business.my.emaildomain.com [01/Dec/2015:00:00:00 +0200] "GET http://Scopus.com.au:80/(S(vdkxl432vozr1dkpsqyoyfj1))/images/tabs-hover.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1164 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
```

I want to annoymize the email address in the logs by replacing  `jamesbond.2015@business.my.emaildomain.com` with `xxx@business.my.emaildomain.com`

Using sed on windows I ran

```
sed s/.*@business.my.emaildomain.com/xxx@business.my.emaildomain.com/ d:\input.txt > d:\output.txt
```

It runs but it replaces everything including `205.200.253.76 6bTxPVZ2aOXEQ5C` with `xxxbusiness.my.emaildomain.com`.

How do I retain the first two "words" and just replace the email?

I've tried

```
sed s/\/b.*@business.my.emaildomain.com/xxx@business.my.emaildomain.com/ d:\input.txt > d:\output.txt
```

and nothing chances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use word boundary character `\b` with `-r` switch for `Extended Regex (ERE)`

```
$ sed -r 's/\b[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+(@business.my.emaildomain.com)/xxxx\1/g'
205.200.253.76 6bTxPVZ2aOXEQ5C jamesbond.2015@business.my.emaildomain.com [01/Dec/2015:00:00:00 +0200] "GET http://Scopus.com.au:80/(S(vdkxl432vozr1dkpsqyoyfj1))/images/tabs-hover.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1164 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
205.200.253.76 6bTxPVZ2aOXEQ5C xxxx@business.my.emaildomain.com [01/Dec/2015:00:00:00 +0200] "GET http://Scopus.com.au:80/(S(vdkxl432vozr1dkpsqyoyfj1))/images/tabs-hover.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1164 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
$
```

Note: above regex limits allowable characters in email id's i.e it must contain only the following chars `[a-zA-Z0-9._]`. If you want any email to be accepted you must use RFC complaint regex (http://emailregex.com/) or maximum allowed charset (as per your application). Above regex helps to replace email address anywhere on a line.

If your log format is fixed you can use the following without worrying about email address being RFC complaint or not..

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s).+(@business.my.emaildomain.com)/\1xxxx\2/g'
205.200.253.76 6bTxPVZ2aOXEQ5C jamesbond.2015@business.my.emaildomain.com [01/Dec/2015:00:00:00 +0200] "GET http://Scopus.com.au:80/(S(vdkxl432vozr1dkpsqyoyfj1))/images/tabs-hover.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1164 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
205.200.253.76 6bTxPVZ2aOXEQ5C xxxx@business.my.emaildomain.com [01/Dec/2015:00:00:00 +0200] "GET http://Scopus.com.au:80/(S(vdkxl432vozr1dkpsqyoyfj1))/images/tabs-hover.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1164 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about -r switch.

Comment: So am I supposed to run $sed -r 's/\b[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(@business.my.emaildomain.com)/xxxx\1/g' d:\input.txt > d:\output.txt

Comment: is it ok for your application to have just these [a-zA-Z0-9._] chars in your email id? If yes, then you can use that or use the 2nd one

Comment: Yes, we just have the normal alphanumeric chars. I am still getting an error though.

Comment: Hmm. Dropping the quotes works. sed -r s/\b[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(@business.my.emaildomain.com)/xxxx\1/g d:\input.txt > d:\output.txt . Strange.

Comment: The error is sed: -e expression #1, char 1: Unknown command: ''' or something

Comment: It is solved when i drop the quotes. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: hmm quotes issue might be specific to windows i guess .. for the above answer i used Linux though.. No problem :)